# Valgrind runs the Systemd

Tags: valgrind, systemd

I'm going to run systemd-243 using valgrind

I boot the system with rw init= pointing to a shell script with the below content ?

[https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2187](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I ran into the following problems：

```
[    0.000000] max_pfn_mapped=256
[    0.000000] max_low_pfn=786428
[    0.000000] max_pfn_mapped=8650752
[    0.000000] max_pfn_mapped=8650752
[    2.972109] memcheck-amd64-[1]: segfault at 1ffeffeed0 ip 00000010030a7bef sp 0000001002bb5e10 error 6
[    2.973197] Code: c7 85 b8 00 00 00 0a 66 00 04 49 8d 9c 24 d0 fa ff ff 48 89 df 48 8b b5 e0 03 00 00 49 c7 c3 80 6f 01 58 41 ff d3 4c 8b 55 40 <4c> 89 13 48 c7 85 b8 00 00 00 11 66 00 04 49 8d 5c 24 28 48 89 df
[    3.764641] systemd[1]: segfault at 1ffeffdfb8 ip 000000100316f90c sp 0000001002bb5e10 error 6
[    3.765659] Code: 00 46 2d 8c 04 4d 8d 97 48 fb ff ff 4c 89 d7 40 89 de 4c 89 95 e0 0a 00 00 49 c7 c3 40 72 01 58 41 ff d3 4c 8b bd e0 0a 00 00 <45> 89 37 48 c7 85 b8 00 00 00 4c 2d 8c 04 4d 8d b5 c0 00 00 00 49
[   10.678484] systemd[1]: segfault at 1ffeffcd88 ip 000000100329135c sp 0000001002bb5e10 error 6
[   10.679506] Code: 00 46 2d 8c 04 4d 8d 97 48 fb ff ff 4c 89 d7 40 89 de 4c 89 95 e0 0a 00 00 49 c7 c3 40 72 01 58 41 ff d3 4c 8b bd e0 0a 00 00 <45> 89 37 48 c7 85 b8 00 00 00 4c 2d 8c 04 4d 8d b5 c0 00 00 00 49
--1:0: aspacem <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: out_of_memory (224 segments)
--1:0: aspacem 33 segment names in 35 slots
--1:0: aspacem freelist begins at 1151
--1:0: aspacem (0,4,9) /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--1:0: aspacem (1,49,8) /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
--1:0: aspacem (2,78,8) /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so
--1:0: aspacem (3,104,1) /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-1-by-???-on-???
--1:0: aspacem (4,155,8) /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--1:0: aspacem (5,209,8) /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--1:0: aspacem (6,267,0) [free slot: size=17  next=0]
--1:0: aspacem (7,288,9) /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.28.so
--1:0: aspacem (8,322,8) /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so
--1:0: aspacem (9,350,8) /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-243.so
--1:0: aspacem (10,396,9) /usr/lib64/librt-2.28.so
--1:0: aspacem (11,425,9) /usr/lib64/libseccomp.so.2.5.0
--1:0: aspacem (12,460,9) /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
--1:0: aspacem (13,491,8) /usr/lib64/libmount.so.1.1.0
--1:0: aspacem (14,524,8) /usr/lib64/libpam.so.0.85.1
--1:0: aspacem (15,556,9) /usr/lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
--1:0: aspacem (16,589,8) /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.3.5
--1:0: aspacem (17,621,9) /usr/lib64/libcap.so.2.32
--1:0: aspacem (18,651,8) /usr/lib64/libacl.so.1.1.2253
--1:0: aspacem (19,685,9) /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.20.2.6
--1:0: aspacem (20,720,8) /usr/lib64/libidn2.so.0.3.7
--1:0: aspacem (21,752,9) /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.5
--1:0: aspacem (22,784,8) /usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1.9.2
--1:0: aspacem (23,815,9) /usr/lib64/libblkid.so.1.1.0
--1:0: aspacem (24,848,8) /usr/lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0.10.0
--1:0: aspacem (25,884,8) /usr/lib64/libdl-2.28.so
--1:0: aspacem (26,913,8) /usr/lib64/libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
--1:0: aspacem (27,947,9) /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.11
--1:0: aspacem (28,977,8) /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1.1f
--1:0: aspacem (29,1012,8) /usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.2448
--1:0: aspacem (30,1047,9) /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.29.0
--1:0: aspacem (31,1085,8) /usr/lib64/libunistring.so.2.1.0
--1:0: aspacem (32,1122,3) /usr/lib64/libsepol.so.1
--1:0: aspacem (33,1151,0) [free slot: size=39  next=267]
--1:0: aspacem (34,1194,1) /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.bin
--1:0: aspacem   0: RSVN 0000000000-0000107fff 1081344 ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem   1: file 0000108000-0000138fff  200704 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584906 o=0       (1,49)
--1:0: aspacem   2: file 0000139000-00001f6fff  778240 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1584906 o=200704  (1,49)
--1:0: aspacem   3: file 00001f7000-000024bfff  348160 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584906 o=978944  (1,49)
--1:0: aspacem   4: file 000024c000-000028ffff  278528 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584906 o=1323008 (1,49)
--1:0: aspacem   5: file 0000290000-0000290fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1584906 o=1601536 (1,49)
--1:0: aspacem   6: RSVN 0000291000-0003ffffff     61m ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem   7: file 0004000000-0004000fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576354 o=0       (2,78)
--1:0: aspacem   8: file 0004001000-0004020fff  131072 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576354 o=4096    (2,78)
--1:0: aspacem   9: file 0004021000-0004027fff   28672 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576354 o=135168  (2,78)
--1:0: aspacem  10: file 0004028000-0004028fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576354 o=159744  (2,78)
--1:0: aspacem  11: file 0004029000-0004029fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576354 o=163840  (2,78)
--1:0: aspacem  12: anon 000402a000-000402afff    4096 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  13: anon 000402b000-000402bfff    4096 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem  14: RSVN 000402c000-000482afff 8384512 ----- SmLower
--1:0: aspacem  15: file 000482b000-000482bfff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585071 o=0       (4,155)
--1:0: aspacem  16: file 000482c000-000482cfff    4096 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1585071 o=4096    (4,155)
--1:0: aspacem  17: file 000482d000-000482dfff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585071 o=8192    (4,155)
--1:0: aspacem  18: file 000482e000-000482efff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585071 o=8192    (4,155)
--1:0: aspacem  19: file 000482f000-000482ffff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1585071 o=12288   (4,155)
--1:0: aspacem  20: anon 0004830000-0004831fff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  21: file 0004832000-0004835fff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585083 o=0       (5,209)
--1:0: aspacem  22: file 0004836000-000483efff   36864 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1585083 o=16384   (5,209)
--1:0: aspacem  23: file 000483f000-0004841fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585083 o=53248   (5,209)
--1:0: aspacem  24: file 0004842000-0004842fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585083 o=61440   (5,209)
--1:0: aspacem  25: file 0004843000-0004843fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1585083 o=65536   (5,209)
--1:0: aspacem  26:      0004844000-0004850fff   53248
--1:0: aspacem  27: file 0004851000-0004857fff   28672 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=0       (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  28: file 0004858000-0004866fff   61440 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=28672   (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  29: file 0004867000-000486afff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=90112   (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  30: file 000486b000-000486bfff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=106496  (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  31: file 000486c000-000486cfff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=106496  (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  32: file 000486d000-000486dfff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576375 o=110592  (7,288)
--1:0: aspacem  33: anon 000486e000-0004871fff   16384 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  34: file 0004872000-0004896fff  151552 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576361 o=0       (8,322)
--1:0: aspacem  35: file 0004897000-00049dafff 1327104 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576361 o=151552  (8,322)
--1:0: aspacem  36: file 00049db000-0004a1ffff  282624 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576361 o=1478656 (8,322)
--1:0: aspacem  37: file 0004a20000-0004a22fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576361 o=1757184 (8,322)
--1:0: aspacem  38: file 0004a23000-0004a25fff   12288 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576361 o=1769472 (8,322)
--1:0: aspacem  39: anon 0004a26000-0004a29fff   16384 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  40: file 0004a2a000-0004a73fff  303104 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584895 o=0       (9,350)
--1:0: aspacem  41: file 0004a74000-0004bd9fff 1466368 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1584895 o=303104  (9,350)
--1:0: aspacem  42: file 0004bda000-0004c58fff  520192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584895 o=1769472 (9,350)
--1:0: aspacem  43: file 0004c59000-0004ce8fff  589824 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1584895 o=2285568 (9,350)
--1:0: aspacem  44: file 0004ce9000-0004ce9fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1584895 o=2875392 (9,350)
--1:0: aspacem  45: anon 0004cea000-0004ceafff    4096 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  46: file 0004ceb000-0004cedfff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=0       (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  47: file 0004cee000-0004cf1fff   16384 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=12288   (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  48: file 0004cf2000-0004cf2fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=28672   (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  49: file 0004cf3000-0004cf3fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=32768   (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  50: file 0004cf4000-0004cf4fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=32768   (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  51: file 0004cf5000-0004cf5fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576379 o=36864   (10,396)
--1:0: aspacem  52: file 0004cf6000-0004cf7fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=0       (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  53: file 0004cf8000-0004d06fff   61440 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=8192    (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  54: file 0004d07000-0004d14fff   57344 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=69632   (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  55: file 0004d15000-0004d15fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=126976  (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  56: file 0004d16000-0004d16fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=126976  (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  57: file 0004d17000-0004d17fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577214 o=131072  (11,425)
--1:0: aspacem  58: anon 0004d18000-0004d19fff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  59: file 0004d1a000-0004d20fff   28672 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576725 o=0       (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  60: file 0004d21000-0004d39fff  102400 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576725 o=28672   (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  61: file 0004d3a000-0004d40fff   28672 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576725 o=131072  (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  62: file 0004d41000-0004d41fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576725 o=159744  (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  63: file 0004d42000-0004d42fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576725 o=159744  (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  64: file 0004d43000-0004d43fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i[   10.747141] serial8250: too much work for irq4
=1576725 o=163840  (12,460)
--1:0: aspacem  65: anon 0004d44000-0004d45fff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  66: file 0004d46000-0004d51fff   49152 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580717 o=0       (13,491)
--1:0: aspacem  67: file 0004d52000-0004d8dfff  245760 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1580717 o=49152   (13,491)
--1:0: aspacem  68: file 0004d8e000-0004da0fff   77824 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580717 o=294912  (13,491)
--1:0: aspacem  69: file 0004da1000-0004da2fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580717 o=368640  (13,491)
--1:0: aspacem  70: file 0004da3000-0004da3fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1580717 o=376832  (13,491)
--1:0: aspacem  71: file 0004da4000-0004da6fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580792 o=0       (14,524)
--1:0: aspacem  72: file 0004da7000-0004daffff   36864 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1580792 o=12288   (14,524)
--1:0: aspacem  73: file 0004db0000-0004db3fff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580792 o=49152   (14,524)
--1:0: aspacem  74: file 0004db4000-0004db4fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580792 o=61440   (14,524)
--1:0: aspacem  75: file 0004db5000-0004db5fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1580792 o=65536   (14,524)
--1:0: aspacem  76: file 0004db6000-0004db8fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=0       (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  77: file 0004db9000-0004dc0fff   32768 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=12288   (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  78: file 0004dc1000-0004dd4fff   81920 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=45056   (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  79: file 0004dd5000-0004dd5fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=126976  (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  80: file 0004dd6000-0004dd6fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=126976  (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  81: file 0004dd7000-0004dd7fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1579476 o=131072  (15,556)
--1:0: aspacem  82: anon 0004dd8000-0004de7fff   65536 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  83: file 0004de8000-0004debfff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580715 o=0       (16,589)
--1:0: aspacem  84: file 0004dec000-0004dfafff   61440 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1580715 o=16384   (16,589)
--1:0: aspacem  85: file 0004dfb000-0004dfffff   20480 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580715 o=77824   (16,589)
--1:0: aspacem  86: file 0004e00000-0004e00fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580715 o=94208   (16,589)
--1:0: aspacem  87: file 0004e01000-0004e01fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1580715 o=98304   (16,589)
--1:0: aspacem  88: file 0004e02000-0004e03fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=0       (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  89: file 0004e04000-0004e06fff   12288 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=8192    (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  90: file 0004e07000-0004e07fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=20480   (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  91: file 0004e08000-0004e08fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=24576   (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  92: file 0004e09000-0004e09fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=24576   (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  93: file 0004e0a000-0004e0afff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576874 o=28672   (17,621)
--1:0: aspacem  94: anon 0004e0b000-0004e0cfff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem  95: file 0004e0d000-0004e0efff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577182 o=0       (18,651)
--1:0: aspacem  96: file 0004e0f000-0004e13fff   20480 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577182 o=8192    (18,651)
--1:0: aspacem  97: file 0004e14000-0004e15fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577182 o=28672   (18,651)
--1:0: aspacem  98: file 0004e16000-0004e16fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577182 o=32768   (18,651)
--1:0: aspacem  99: file 0004e17000-0004e17fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577182 o=36864   (18,651)
--1:0: aspacem 100: file 0004e18000-0004e23fff   49152 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=0       (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 101: file 0004e24000-0004ef7fff  868352 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=49152   (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 102: file 0004ef8000-0004f33fff  245760 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=917504  (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 103: file 0004f34000-0004f34fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=1163264 (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 104: file 0004f35000-0004f36fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=1163264 (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 105: file 0004f37000-0004f3cfff   24576 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577130 o=1171456 (19,685)
--1:0: aspacem 106: file 0004f3d000-0004f3efff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577189 o=0       (20,720)
--1:0: aspacem 107: file 0004f3f000-0004f43fff   20480 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577189 o=8192    (20,720)
--1:0: aspacem 108: file 0004f44000-0004f5cfff  102400 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577189 o=28672   (20,720)
--1:0: aspacem 109: file 0004f5d000-0004f5dfff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577189 o=126976  (20,720)
--1:0: aspacem 110: file 0004f5e000-0004f5efff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577189 o=131072  (20,720)
--1:0: aspacem 111: file 0004f5f000-0004f61fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=0       (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 112: file 0004f62000-0004f79fff   98304 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=12288   (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 113: file 0004f7a000-0004f84fff   45056 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=110592  (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 114: file 0004f85000-0004f85fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=155648  (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 115: file 0004f86000-0004f86fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=155648  (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 116: file 0004f87000-0004f87fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576872 o=159744  (21,752)
--1:0: aspacem 117: file 0004f88000-0004f89fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580173 o=0       (22,784)
--1:0: aspacem 118: file 0004f8a000-0004fb7fff  188416 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1580173 o=8192    (22,784)
--1:0: aspacem 119: file 0004fb8000-0004fbafff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580173 o=196608  (22,784)
--1:0: aspacem 120: file 0004fbb000-0004fbbfff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1580173 o=204800  (22,784)
--1:0: aspacem 121: file 0004fbc000-0004fbcfff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1580173 o=208896  (22,784)
--1:0: aspacem 122: file 0004fbd000-0004fc5fff   36864 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=0       (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 123: file 0004fc6000-0004ff8fff  208896 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=36864   (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 124: file 0004ff9000-0005008fff   65536 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=245760  (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 125: file 0005009000-0005009fff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=311296  (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 126: file 000500a000-000500dfff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=311296  (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 127: file 000500e000-000500efff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1583956 o=327680  (23,815)
--1:0: aspacem 128: anon 000500f000-0005010fff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 129: file 0005011000-0005012fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579963 o=0       (24,848)
--1:0: aspacem 130: file 0005013000-000507bfff  430080 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1579963 o=8192    (24,848)
--1:0: aspacem 131: file 000507c000-00050a4fff  167936 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579963 o=438272  (24,848)
--1:0: aspacem 132: file 00050a5000-00050a5fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579963 o=602112  (24,848)
--1:0: aspacem 133: file 00050a6000-00050a6fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1579963 o=606208  (24,848)
--1:0: aspacem 134: file 00050a7000-00050a7fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576363 o=0       (25,884)
--1:0: aspacem 135: file 00050a8000-00050a8fff    4096 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576363 o=4096    (25,884)
--1:0: aspacem 136: file 00050a9000-00050a9fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576363 o=8192    (25,884)
--1:0: aspacem 137: file 00050aa000-00050aafff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576363 o=8192    (25,884)
--1:0: aspacem 138: file 00050ab000-00050abfff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576363 o=12288   (25,884)
--1:0: aspacem 139: file 00050ac000-00050adfff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576930 o=0       (26,913)
--1:0: aspacem 140: file 00050ae000-00050b0fff   12288 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576930 o=8192    (26,913)
--1:0: aspacem 141: file 00050b1000-00050b1fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576930 o=20480   (26,913)
--1:0: aspacem 142: file 00050b2000-00050b2fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576930 o=20480   (26,913)
--1:0: aspacem 143: file 00050b3000-00050b3fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576930 o=24576   (26,913)
--1:0: aspacem 144: file 00050b4000-00050b6fff   12288 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=0       (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 145: file 00050b7000-00050c4fff   57344 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=12288   (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 146: file 00050c5000-00050cafff   24576 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=69632   (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 147: file 00050cb000-00050cbfff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=94208   (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 148: file 00050cc000-00050ccfff [   10.807346] serial8250: too much work for irq4
   4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=94208   (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 149: file 00050cd000-00050cdfff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576743 o=98304   (27,947)
--1:0: aspacem 150: file 00050ce000-0005147fff  499712 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579950 o=0       (28,977)
--1:0: aspacem 151: file 0005148000-00052e8fff 1708032 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1579950 o=499712  (28,977)
--1:0: aspacem 152: file 00052e9000-000537cfff  606208 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579950 o=2207744 (28,977)
--1:0: aspacem 153: file 000537d000-00053a8fff  180224 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1579950 o=2809856 (28,977)
--1:0: aspacem 154: file 00053a9000-00053acfff   16384 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1579950 o=2990080 (28,977)
--1:0: aspacem 155: anon 00053ad000-00053b0fff   16384 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 156: file 00053b1000-00053b2fff    8192 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577172 o=0       (29,1012)
--1:0: aspacem 157: file 00053b3000-00053b5fff   12288 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577172 o=8192    (29,1012)
--1:0: aspacem 158: file 00053b6000-00053b6fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577172 o=20480   (29,1012)
--1:0: aspacem 159: file 00053b7000-00053b7fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577172 o=20480   (29,1012)
--1:0: aspacem 160: file 00053b8000-00053b8fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577172 o=24576   (29,1012)
--1:0: aspacem 161: anon 00053b9000-00053bafff    8192 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 162: file 00053bb000-00053befff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=0       (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 163: file 00053bf000-00053d3fff   86016 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=16384   (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 164: file 00053d4000-00053ddfff   40960 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=102400  (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 165: file 00053de000-00053defff    4096 ----- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=143360  (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 166: file 00053df000-00053dffff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=143360  (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 167: file 00053e0000-00053e0fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1576905 o=147456  (30,1047)
--1:0: aspacem 168: file 00053e1000-00053f1fff   69632 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577186 o=0       (31,1085)
--1:0: aspacem 169: file 00053f2000-0005428fff  225280 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1577186 o=69632   (31,1085)
--1:0: aspacem 170: file 0005429000-000555ffff 1273856 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577186 o=294912  (31,1085)
--1:0: aspacem 171: file 0005560000-0005563fff   16384 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1577186 o=1564672 (31,1085)
--1:0: aspacem 172: file 0005564000-0005564fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1577186 o=1581056 (31,1085)
--1:0: aspacem 173: anon 0005565000-0005569fff   20480 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 174: anon 000556a000-0005969fff 4194304 rwx-H
--1:0: aspacem 175: file 000596a000-00059f3fff  565248 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1181074 o=0       (34,1194)
--1:0: aspacem 176:      00059f4000-000626afff 8876032
--1:0: aspacem 177: anon 000626b000-000ca6afff    104m rwx-H
--1:0: aspacem 178:      000ca6b000-00136bafff    108m
--1:0: aspacem 179: anon 00136bb000-0013ebafff 8388608 rwx-H
--1:0: aspacem 180:      0013ebb000-0057ffffff   1089m
--1:0: aspacem 181: FILE 0058000000-0058000fff    4096 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=0       (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 182: FILE 0058001000-0058061fff  397312 r-x-- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=4096    (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 183: file 0058062000-0058062fff    4096 r-xT- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=401408  (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 184: FILE 0058063000-00581acfff 1351680 r-x-- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=405504  (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 185: FILE 00581ad000-0058242fff  614400 r---- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=1757184 (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 186:      0058243000-0058243fff    4096
--1:0: aspacem 187: FILE 0058244000-0058249fff   24576 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1585004 o=2371584 (0,4)
--1:0: aspacem 188: ANON 005824a000-0059c4bfff     26m rw---
--1:0: aspacem 189:      0059c4c000-1001ffffff  64131m
--1:0: aspacem 190: RSVN 1002000000-1002000fff    4096 ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem 191: ANON 1002001000-1002a33fff     10m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 192:      1002a34000-1002a49fff   90112
--1:0: aspacem 193: ANON 1002a4a000-1002a8afff  266240 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 194:      1002a8b000-1002a8bfff    4096
--1:0: aspacem 195: ANON 1002a8c000-1002ab3fff  163840 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 196: ANON 1002ab4000-1002ab5fff    8192 -----
--1:0: aspacem 197: ANON 1002ab6000-1002bb5fff 1048576 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 198: ANON 1002bb6000-1002bb7fff    8192 -----
--1:0: aspacem 199: FILE 1002bb8000-1002bb8fff    4096 rw--- d=0xfd00 i=1970345 o=0       (3,104)
--1:0: aspacem 200: ANON 1002bb9000-1002c78fff  786432 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 201:      1002c79000-1002c7bfff   12288
--1:0: aspacem 202: ANON 1002c7c000-1005c9bfff     48m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 203:      1005c9c000-1005c9cfff    4096
--1:0: aspacem 204: ANON 1005c9d000-1007e88fff     33m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 205:      1007e89000-1007e89fff    4096
--1:0: aspacem 206: ANON 1007e8a000-1009ed5fff     32m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 207:      1009ed6000-1009ed6fff    4096
--1:0: aspacem 208: ANON 1009ed7000-100ac36fff     13m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 209:      100ac37000-100ac3afff   16384
--1:0: aspacem 210: ANON 100ac3b000-100b0eafff 4915200 rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 211:      100b0eb000-100b2fafff 2162688
--1:0: aspacem 212: ANON 100b2fb000-10104affff     81m rwx--
--1:0: aspacem 213:      10104b0000-1ffe800fff  65251m
--1:0: aspacem 214: RSVN 1ffe801000-1ffeffbfff 8368128 ----- SmUpper
--1:0: aspacem 215: anon 1ffeffc000-1fff000fff   20480 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 216:      1fff001000-1fffffffff     15m
--1:0: aspacem 217: RSVN 2000000000-7ffda759cfff 130934g ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem 218: ANON 7ffda759d000-7ffda75bdfff  135168 rw---
--1:0: aspacem 219: RSVN 7ffda75be000-7ffda75d6fff  102400 ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem 220: ANON 7ffda75d7000-7ffda75d9fff   12288 r----
--1:0: aspacem 221: RSVN 7ffda75da000-ffffffffff5fffff  16383e ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem 222: ANON ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff600fff    4096 r-x--
--1:0: aspacem 223: RSVN ffffffffff601000-ffffffffffffffff      9m ----- SmFixed
--1:0: aspacem >>>
[   10.855312] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
[   10.855312] 
[   10.856364] CPU: 14 PID: 1 Comm: systemd Not tainted 4.18.0-147.5.2.14.h1028.eulerosv2r10.x86_64 #1
[   10.857387] Hardware name: Red Hat KVM, BIOS 0.5.1 01/01/2011
[   10.858038] Call Trace:
[   10.858337]  panic+0xe4/0x392
[   10.858685]  do_exit+0xc3e/0xc40
[   10.859057]  do_group_exit+0x33/0xb0
[   10.859470]  __x64_sys_exit_group+0x14/0x20
[   10.859952]  do_syscall_64+0x5d/0x1d0
[   10.860383]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x65/0xca
[   10.860963] RIP: 0033:0x58060599
[   10.861341] Code: Bad RIP value.
[   10.861713] RSP: 002b:0000001002bb5b58 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000e7
[   10.862571] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000058060599
[   10.863383] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000001
[   10.864186] RBP: 0000000000004000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   10.864994] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 00000000170d9000
[   10.865798] R13: 0000000000004000 R14: 0000000059255c40 R15: 00000000059f0000
[   10.866611] kernel fault(0x5) notification starting on CPU 14
[   10.867265] kernel fault(0x5) notification finished on CPU 14
[   10.869070] Kernel Offset: 0x2e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   10.870274] kernel reboot(0x2) notification starting on CPU 14
[   10.870935] kernel reboot(0x2) notification finished on CPU 14
```

There's a solution, but he doesn't work for me：
[https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/17205](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

So, how do you run systemd in valgrind?

Answer (score 0):

"So, how do you run systemd in valgrind?"

I use FreeBSD :-)

There is a big clue here

`--1:0: aspacem <<< SHOW_SEGMENTS: out_of_memory (224 segments)`

Also I presume that the Valgrind output is truncated, and this part of the message is missing:

```
   const HChar* s1 = 
      "\n"
      "    Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:\n"
      "       %s's request for %llu bytes failed.\n"
      "       %'13llu bytes have already been mmap-ed ANONYMOUS.\n"
      "    Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.\n\n"
      "    There are several possible reasons for this.\n"
      "    - You have some kind of memory limit in place.  Look at the\n"
      "      output of 'ulimit -a'.  Is there a limit on the size of\n"
      "      virtual memory or address space?\n"
      "    - You have run out of swap space.\n"
      "    - Valgrind has a bug.  If you think this is the case or you are\n"
      "    not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.\n"
      "    Please note that programs can take substantially more memory than\n"
      "    normal when running under Valgrind tools, eg. up to twice or\n"
      "    more, depending on the tool.  On a 64-bit machine, Valgrind\n"
      "    should be able to make use of up 32GB memory.  On a 32-bit\n"
      "    machine, Valgrind should be able to use all the memory available\n"
      "    to a single process, up to 4GB if that's how you have your\n"
      "    kernel configured.  Most 32-bit Linux setups allow a maximum of\n"
      "    3GB per process.\n\n"
      "    Whatever the reason, Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.\n";
```

For a start, you need to get the full Valgrind output and see where it is failing and the size of the failing allocation.